# Why does std::condition_variable::wait_for() return with timeout if duration too large?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following behavior was seen under g++ 11.2.1 . The `std::condition_variable` `wait_for` method returns immediately if the timeout variable is too large. In particular in the program below, if `num_years==1`, then the program hangs waiting as expected (presumably for 1 year), but if the variable `num_years==1000` then the program returns immediatly.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug in g++? And a related question, how do you make the `cv.wait_for()` wait indefinitely, instead of guessing a large timeout value?

```cpp
//  This is 'cv_wait.cc' compile with:
//  
//    g++ -o cv_wait -std=c++2a cv_wait.cc
//
// An example showing that wait_for() returns immediately with a timeout
// return value if the duration variable is "too large".
//

#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex cv_m;

  // If num_years is "too large", e.g. 1000, then cv.wait_for()
  // returns immediately with a timeout condition!
  int num_years = 1;  // If 1000 then cv.wait_for() returns immediately!
  std::chrono::seconds timeout((uint64_t)3600 * 24 * 365 * num_years);
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cv_m);
  if (cv.wait_for(lock, timeout, [] { return false; }))
      std::cerr << "No timeout!\n";
  else
      std::cerr << "Timeout!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an overflow bug under the hood of `condition_variable::wait_for`.  Internally it is waiting using `steady_clock` which counts `nanoseconds`.  This clock overflows at +/-292 years.  So when 1000 years gets converted to `nanoseconds`, it is overflowing.

This looks like a standards bug as opposed to an implementation bug: http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition#condvar-24

The implementation should check for overflows of this type and in case found, just wait for the maximum time it is capable of waiting for.